# Azure file image path using java

Tags: java, spring, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

Hi I am trying to save image on azure storage , I already have configuration step and I have upload method

```
AsynchronousFileChannel fileChannel = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(sourceFile.toPath());
    TransferManager.uploadFileToBlockBlob(fileChannel, blob, 8 * 1024 * 1024, null).subscribe(response -> {
        System.out.println("Completed upload request.");
        System.out.println(response.response().statusCode());

    });
```

How can I get the url image path on azure to save it on database and show it on my website?

Comment: Can you edit your question and include how you're creating `blob` object in your code? You can try `blob.toURL()` method to get the URL of the blob.

Comment: @GauravMantri after a blob.toURL(); i get "https://myaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/test/testURL/" how can i access to my images ?

Answer (score 1):

As @GauravMantri said, you can get the URL of a blob via `blob.toURL()`. Then, if the container of the blob is public (be set public access level) and the `ContentType` property of the blob is set correctly like `image/png`, you can directly access the image via the url, such as to use in an `img` tag to show in a web page below.

```
<img src="myaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/test/testURL">
```

However, considering for secure access, a container is set private access level, please refer to the offical documents [`Secure access to an application's data in the cloud`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-secure-access-application) and [`Using shared access signatures (SAS)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json). Then, we need to generate a blob url with SAS signature for accessing.

Here is the sample code to generate a blob url with SAS signature.

```
SharedKeyCredentials credentials = new SharedKeyCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
ServiceSASSignatureValues values = new ServiceSASSignatureValues()
                .withProtocol(SASProtocol.HTTPS_ONLY) // Users MUST use HTTPS (not HTTP).
                .withExpiryTime(OffsetDateTime.now().plusDays(2)) // 2 days before expiration.
                .withContainerName(containerName)
                .withBlobName(blobName);
BlobSASPermission permission = new BlobSASPermission()
                .withRead(true)
                .withAdd(true)
                .withWrite(true);
values.withPermissions(permission.toString());
SASQueryParameters serviceParams = values.generateSASQueryParameters(credentials);
String sasSign = serviceParams.encode();
String blobUrlWithSAS = String.format(Locale.ROOT, "https://%s.blob.core.windows.net/%s/%s%s",
                accountName, containerName, blobName, sasSign);
```

You also can add the SAS signature at the end of the string of `blob.toURL()`.

```
String blobUrlWithSAS = blob.toString()+sasSign;
```

About SAS Signature, you can refer to these sample codes in [`ServiceSASSignatureValues Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.servicesassignaturevalues?view=azure-java-stable) and [`AccountSASSignatureValues Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.accountsassignaturevalues?view=azure-java-stable).