# Azure Function: Download image from storage as stream and upload it again breaks it

Tags: node.js, azure, stream, azure-functions

I am working with azure function in nodeJS. Originally I wanted to download an image as a buffer, add it to my zip file (with adm-zip) and then upload it again. However, the image could not be displayed after unzipping. To download the image I used `createReadStream` then allocated a buffer from the stream and then added it to the zip, saved the zip and uploaded it with `createBlobFromText`. Everything else here works fine, I tried adding a `test.txt` and that was added normally. So there must be a problem with my image stream.

So I tried just downloading the img as a buffer and directly upload it again to my storage. And as a result, the image is broken and cannot be opened.  To download the image I use `createReadStream`. Then allocate a buffer with the stream and then upload the buffer with `createBlockBlobFromText`.

**So my question is, am I handling streams with images wrong?**

**Is there a better way to get the image and continue working with it?**

Thanks!

Here is my code with the zip:

```
const storage = require('azure-storage');
const STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME = 'something';
const ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY = 'somekey';
let AdmZip = require('adm-zip');

const blobService = storage.createBlobService(STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY);

module.exports = function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    var container = 'container';
    var file = 'powerpoint.pptx';
    var data = [],
    dataLen = 0;


    var stream = blobService.createReadStream(container, file);

    stream.on('data', (chunk) => {
        context.log(`Received ${chunk.length} bytes of data.`);
        data.push(chunk);
        dataLen += chunk.length;
    });
    stream.on('end', () => {
        getImageAsBuffer(container, 'test-image.png').then((imgBuf) => {
            var buf = Buffer.alloc(dataLen);

            for (var i = 0, len = data.length, pos = 0; i < len; i++) {
                data[i].copy(buf, pos);
                pos += data[i].length;
            }
            var zip = new AdmZip(buf);

            zip.deleteFile("/ppt/media/image1.png");

            zip.addFile("/ppt/media/image1.png", Buffer.alloc(imgBuf.dataLen, imgBuf.data));
            var powerpoint = zip.toBuffer();

            uploadRemoteFile(powerpoint, container, 'new-powerpoint.pptx').then((res) => {
                context.log('res', res);
                context.done();
            })
        })
    });
};

function uploadRemoteFile(buffer, containerName, filename) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        blobService.createBlockBlobFromText(containerName, filename, buffer, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve({
                    message: 'resolved successfully'
                });
            }
        })
    });
}

function getImageAsBuffer(container, file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         var imgData = [],
             imgLen = 0;
         var imgStream = blobService.createReadStream(container, file);

         imgStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
            imgData.push(chunk);
            imgLen += chunk.length;
         });

         imgStream.on('end', () => {
             resolve({
                 "data": imgData,
                 "dataLen": imgLen
             })
         })
    })
```

}

Comment: Regarding how to download image from blob with node.js, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54422445/need-help-downloading-image-from-azure-blobs-using-nodejs

Comment: @test123 not really, this doesn't really cover any of my questions and is more about public access of blobs / and not being authorized. But I have access and I get the block, I just somehow break it. And additionally the question does not cover getting them in streams, but thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

One issue I see in your code is that you're using `createBlockBlobFromText` method to upload binary content. You will need to use `createBlockBlobFromStream` method.

You can do something like the following:

```
const stream = require('stream');

function uploadRemoteFile(buffer, containerName, filename) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough({
        highWaterMark: buffer.length
      });
      bufferStream.end(buffer);
      blobService.createBlockBlobFromStream(containerName, filename, bufferStream, buffer.length, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve({
            message: 'resolved successfully'
          });
        }
      })
  });
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! Quick question: where does the "data" come from in the `bufferStream.end(data)`?

Comment: oh okay! I looked further in the documentation of createBlockBlobFromStream (https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/azure-storage-legacy/latest/BlobService.html) and it seems like I need some more parameters than just the filename and the container and stream

Comment: this doesn't really work, it seems like the length of the stream is missing. No clue how to get that

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the error? I also edited my answer (added buffer.length parameter). Can you please try now?

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately I still can't open the image, still the error "Cannot open file. It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognise." So it seems like an error with the stream of the image and processing maybe